# Inserting data in Referenced Documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to insert data into myMongoDB database, i am using Referenced Documents, but i couldn't find any convenient method to insert data (while fetching is super convenient).
Please Read It before marking duplicate, I've searched whole Stackoverflow and github before posting
This is my **Exam Schema**

```
const ExamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {},
    description: {},
    allowedTime: {},
    subject: {},
    assignedInCharge: {},
    questions: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MCQuestion' }]
});
```

And Follows is my **Question Schema**:

```
const MultipleChoiceQuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: {},
    answerOptions: [{}],
    correctAnswer: {},
    marksForCorrectAnswer: {},
    negativeMark: {},
    difficulty: {}
});
```

My Question is: Is there any Build-In method in mongoose to put data in database that I'm missing in the documentation (I've already searched it a thousand times there).

**My Input will be as follows:**

```
{
    "name": "Sample Exam 1",
    "description": "IDK if this will work",
    "allowedTime": 123445666,
    "subject": "testsub1",
    "assignedInCharge": "someincharge",
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "this is que1",
            "answerOptions": ["this is op 1", "this is op 2", "op 3", "op 4"],
            "correctAnswer": "this is op 1",
            "marksForCorrectAnswer": 4,
            "negativeMark": 1,
            "difficulty": 3
        },
        {}, {}, {}
    ]
}
```

And (sorry for long snippets) what I'm trying to do to insert data into database is:

```
router.post('/admin/createExam', (request, response) => {

    questions = request.body.questions;
    var idarray = [];

    questions.forEach(function(element) {
        var question = new MCQuestion(element);
        question.save().then((doc) => idarray.push(doc._id), (error) => console.log(error));
    });

    var body = _.pick(request.body, ['Everything Except Questions']);
    body.questions = idarray;

    var exam = new Exam(body);  

    exam.save().then(() =>{
        response.send(exam);
    }).catch((error) => {
        response.status(400).send(error);
    });

});
```

I am able to successfully save the questions into the questions collection, but the Exam Collection is not being saved correctly.

[**The Questions collection**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjJWL.png)

[**The Exam Collection**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmbaM.png)

Please help me, I've been pulling my hairs on this for weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i figured it out, Changing The API method made it good

```
router.post('/admin/createExam', (request, response) => {

    var body = _.pick(request.body, ['name', 'description', 'allowedTime', 'subject', 'assignedInCharge']);
    var exam = new Exam(body);

    request.body.questions.forEach(function(element) {
        element.exam = exam._id;
        var question = new MCQuestion(element);
        exam.questions.push(question._id);
        question.save().catch((error) => console.log(error));
    });

    exam.save().then(() =>{
        response.send(exam);
    }).catch((error) => response.status(400).send(error));

});
```